# How can I create an image with Java?

Tags: java, image

I would like to create a gif image of a filled red circle on a green background. What is the easiest way to do it in Java?

Answer (score 1):

Create a BufferedImage and then write it to a file with `ImageIO.write(image, "gif", fileName)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have an image file or image URL, then you can use [Toolkit](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html) to get an [Image](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html):

```
Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(filename);
```

If you need to construct a new image raster and paint into the image, then you can use [BufferedImage](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html). You can paint onto a BufferedImage, by calling its [createGraphics](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#createGraphics%28%29) function and painting on the graphics object. To save the BufferedImage into a GIF, you can use the [ImageIO](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) class to write out the image.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to generate a `BufferedImage`:

```
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(int width, int height, int imageType) 
// you can find the Types variables in the api
```

Then, generated the [Graphics2D](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html) of this image, this object allows you to set a background and to draw shapes:

```
Graphics2D g = img.createGraphics();
g.setBackground(Color color) ; //Find how to built this object look at the java api
g.draw(Shape s);
g.dispose(); //don't forget it!!!
```

To built the image:

```
File file = new File(dir, name);
try{
  ImageIO.write(img, "gif", file);
}catch(IOException e){
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```